# javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap issue

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, pom.xml

I have an API ENDPOINT that been build with REST, when i try to call it from my application (spring boot) locally it works.

**it gives the error exactly on 'request'.
But after deploying the app in a server it gives this error in tomcat/pom.xml depandency:

```
<!-- new -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end new -->
```

> 2018-07-25 15:15:17 ERROR ErrorPageFilter:176 - Forwarding to error page from request [/api/test/test-claim] due to exception [javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V]
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.accept(ClientRequest.java:336)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:221)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:59)
>           at dd.test.vfg.rrr.cf.ClassTest.methodeTest(ClassTest.java:543)
>           at dd.test.vfg.sr.rest.submitClaim(submitClaim.java:72)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: I suspect glass fish ships with its own version of the API not compatible with the one you are using. When deploying make sure you set the class loading to parent last (i.e. application first) to prefer classes from the archive over those from the server.

Comment: thats how i do it (and btw my app is deployed on tomcat)
javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = client.target(api)
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .post(Entity.entity(entity, entitytest.getMediaType()));

Comment: I noticed `glass fish` in the stacktrace, and jumped to the GlassFish conclusion. Apparently you don't get the version of the API you expect to get. Check the generated war and check what is included in there.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: Don't add additional information as comments, those become unreadable. Edit your question.

Comment: upp............